# cursor hand symbol change in radhtmlchart columnseries chart

Tags: telerik, cursor, symbols, radhtmlchart

Please suggest on how to show the hand symbol on mouse hover of the telerik radhtmlchart.AS of now im getting only pointer symbol on mouse hover.

```
<telerik:radhtmlchart runat="server" id="RadHtmlChartfirst" onclientseriesclicked="OnClientSeriesClickedfirst"
                    legend-appearance-position="Top" legend-appearance-visible="true" plotarea-xaxis-minorgridlines-visible="false"
                    plotarea-yaxis-minorgridlines-visible="false" plotarea-xaxis-majorgridlines-visible="false"
                    plotarea-yaxis-majorgridlines-visible="false" height="444" width="900">
                    <PlotArea>
                        <Series>
                            <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="myValues1" Name="Name1">
                            </telerik:ColumnSeries>
                            <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="myValues2" Name="Name2">
                            </telerik:ColumnSeries>
                            <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="myValues3" Name="Name3">
                            </telerik:ColumnSeries>
                        </Series>
                        <XAxis DataLabelsField="myLabels">
                        </XAxis>
                    </PlotArea>
                    <Legend>
                        <Appearance Visible="true" Position="Bottom" />
                    </Legend>
                    <Appearance>
                        <FillStyle BackgroundColor="" />
                    </Appearance>
                    <ChartTitle Text="Reviewer Utilization Report">
                    </ChartTitle>
                </telerik:radhtmlchart>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in facility for that because this chart renders SVG and the cursor styles generally apply to HTML elements. I tried the following flimsy mouse event handling and it seems to kind of work though:

```
        <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="chart" onmouseout="onmouseoutHandler();">
            <ClientEvents OnSeriesHover="OnSeriesHover" />
            <PlotArea>
                <Series>
                    <telerik:ColumnSeries Name="first">
                        <SeriesItems>
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="1" />
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="2" />
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="3" />
                        </SeriesItems>
                    </telerik:ColumnSeries>
                    <telerik:ColumnSeries Name="second">
                        <SeriesItems>
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="1" />
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="2" />
                            <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="3" />
                        </SeriesItems>
                    </telerik:ColumnSeries>
                </Series>
            </PlotArea>
        </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
        <script>
            function OnSeriesHover(e) {
                document.onmouseover = null;
                if (e.series.name == "first") { //consider adding some conditions or removing them at all
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer"
                    }, 50);
                }
                return false;
            }

            //attached to onmouseout of the chart wrapper to restore the cursor
            //as soon as the mouse moves on the chart
            function onmouseoutHandler(e) {
                document.body.onmouseover = restoreCursor;
            }
            //the handler that restores the cursor for the page
            function restoreCursor() {
                document.body.style.cursor = "";
            }
            //resets the cursor
            document.body.onmouseover = restoreCursor;
        </script>
```

and I had to add this CSS to ensure my body element is large enough:

```
        html, body, form
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Its not working for me ... please help me in fixing this as client needs hand symbol because it is  kind of drilldown chart.

Comment: What is your Telerik version? I used the latest. Probably a year ago the events of the chart changed a bit. Upgrade or review the available properties for something similar. OnClientSeriesHovered sounds probable for the old name

Comment: Here is the same approach from the telerik forums. It seems to use the old events as the thread is old http://www.telerik.com/forums/hand-cursor-on-series-for-drilldown